# Error with aldryn_bootstrap3: Field defines a relation with model '...', which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

When I run `migrate.py` in my virtualenv, I recieve the following error:

```
$ python manage.py migrate aldryn_bootstrap3
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
aldryn_bootstrap3.Boostrap3ButtonPlugin.link_file: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'File', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
aldryn_bootstrap3.Boostrap3ImagePlugin.file: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Image', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
aldryn_bootstrap3.Bootstrap3CarouselSlideFolderPlugin.folder: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Folder', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
aldryn_bootstrap3.Bootstrap3CarouselSlidePlugin.image: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Image', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
aldryn_bootstrap3.Bootstrap3CarouselSlidePlugin.link_file: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'File', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
aldryn_bootstrap3.Bootstrap3FilePlugin.file: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'File', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

I've added `aldryn_bootstrap3` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `settings.py`.

Comment: Have you added django-filer to the installed apps? http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration

Comment: Nope, I'll try that. Is it necessary to install "south"?

Comment: Wohoooo!! It works!! I've added filer and migrated normally!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aldryn Bootstrap3 depends on [django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer). You should [install it first](http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'filer',
    'mptt',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    ...
]
```

The errors you are getting (*Field defines a relation with model 'File', which is either not installed, or is abstract*) are telling you that some models depend on other models that Django cannot find.

Specifically, in this case, Aldryn Bootstrap3 models depend on the models `File`, `Image` and `Folder` that are defined in django-filer.